# How to extent the range of contours

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, python-3.6

### The issue

below code plots a contour plot almost as I want. The issues with the results is that I don't know how to extent the range for which contour lines (or colours for colour maps) are plotted.

I set `colors = 'k'` to ensure no line disappears on the white background.
I tried to modify the contour line range with `CS.set_clim(0.01,0.4)`. Even `CS.set_clim(0.01,0.1)` does not change the image. I expected lines >= .1 to vanish.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats as ss
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x, y = np.mgrid[-2.5:2.5:.01, -2.5:2.5:.01]
pos = np.dstack((x, y))
rv = ss.multivariate_normal([0.0, 0.0], [[1.0, 0.], [0., 1.]])
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(x, y, rv.pdf(pos), colors = 'k')
CS.set_clim(0.01,0.4)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

[image: contour plot, but without the wanted line range]

### How do I define the range in which contour lines will be displayed?

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Probably not exactly what you want but you can be very specific in which contours to plot by setting `levels`. E.g.: `plt.contour(x, y, rv.pdf(pos), colors = 'k', levels=np.linspace(0.01, 0.1, 10))`

Comment: Thank you, kazemakase. That may very well be the solution. I guess I don't understand `set_clim()` yet.

Comment: Did you maybe take "clim" to mean countour limit? That is not the case. It actually stands for color limit and is used for setting the range of values mapped to a colormap when showing an image. I don't know if it has an effect on `countour` or `contourf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just post the answer kazemakase gave in a comment to my question so I can mark it as solved.
The levels can be set using the `levels` keyword in `plt.contour()`. If one wants regularly spaced contour lines you can calculate them with e.g. 
`levels = [rv.pdf(q) for q in np.arange(2.0, 0.0, -0.1)]`. I use negative increments to calculate the PDF because the plotting functions requires increasing levels.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats as ss
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x, y = np.mgrid[-2.5:2.5:.01, -2.5:2.5:.01]
pos = np.dstack((x, y))
rv = ss.multivariate_normal([0.0, 0.0], [[1.0, 0.], [0., 1.]])
levels = [rv.pdf(q) for q in np.arange(2.0, 0.0, -0.1)]
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(x, y, rv.pdf(pos), levels = levels)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```